# Custom http return code

Tags: .net, wcf, webdav

I want to create a WebDAV server based on WCF restful services. Is it possible to return message with custom http code 207 Multi-status? Unfortunately I cannot use WebOperationContext because System.Net.HttpStatusCode enum does not seem to support http code extensions described in webdav rfc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System.Net.HttpStatusCode is an enum over an int type, effectively just more readable code. Try using `(HttpStatusCode) 207`.

Comment: @pg0xC There is a StatusDescription property that appears to be read/write (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.outgoingwebresponsecontext.statusdescription.aspx). Does setting it not work?